# How to show an integral representation for the logarithmic derivative of the Riemann zeta function?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory

Prove that the logarithmic derivative of the Riemann zeta function $$-\frac{\zeta^{\prime}(s)}{\zeta(s)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{n^s}=s\int_{1}^{\infty}\psi(x)x^{-s-1}\, d\mathrm{x},$$ where $\Lambda(n)$ is the Mangoldt function and $\psi(x)=\sum_{n\leq x} \Lambda(n)$ (Chebychev function), $Re(s)>1$.

I found this result in page 172 of the book Number Theory an Introduction via the Distribution of Primes by Benjamin Fire but I am not able to prove it.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? You need to [provide context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) for your question. Otherwise it just looks like you want somebody to do your homework for you; that's not what this site is for. If you add some appropriate context, we will be happy to help.

Comment: It follows from differentiating the $\log$ of the Euler product, expanding $1/(1-p^{-s})$ in geometric series and using $n^{-s}=s\int_n^\infty x^{-s-1}dx$.

Comment: @GregMartin Said context has been added, you can make comments or vote to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@reuns has summarised it already. I'll get you started. Since $-\ln\zeta(s)=\sum_{p\in\Bbb P}\ln(1-p^{-s})$,$$-\frac{\zeta^\prime(s)}{\zeta(s)}=\sum_{p\in\Bbb P}\frac{p^{-s}\ln p}{1-p^{-s}}=\sum_{p\in\Bbb P,\,k\ge1}p^{-ks}\ln p=\sum_{n\ge1}\Lambda(n)n^{-s}=s\int_n^\infty\sum_{n\ge1}\Lambda(n)x^{-s-1}dx.$$You can rewrite this in terms of $\psi$ with the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket), which I'll leave you to try.